Liquidity property of an uniswap V3 pool is higher than the actual reserves - why?
As far as I understood, the liquidity property of an Uniswap V3 pool reflects the current in-range liquidity, and it is stored as the square root of x*y.
So if we check the liquidity of this contract here on etherscan, we (currently) see the number
8569999606140360914.
So to get the real k amount, I have to multiply this number by itself which returns
73,444,893,249,245,941,191,375,300,954,178,915,396

To verify, I took the amounts which etherscan shows in the "Token Holdings" dropdown, of token0 and token1 in wei, which are
19226 WETH = 19226000000000000000000 wei (18 digits)
20158206 USDC = 20158206000000 wei (6 digits)

When I multiply 19226000000000000000000 and 20158206000000 I get
387,561,668,556,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

which is in fact much smaller than the "real" k amount I get from the liquiditiy property of the contract.
So how can the current in-range liquidity be higher than the actual reserves of the pool? Where is my mistake here?

This is because Uniswap v3 introduces concentrated liquidity. It allows the capital to be more efficient. For details, see this question.
In your example, we can compute the concentration factor by comparing the V3 liquidity and the V2 liquidity that would correspond to the token amounts if the xy=k formula was used:
>>> L_v3 = 8569999606140360914
>>> L_v2 = sqrt(19226000000000000000000 * 20158206000000)
>>> L_v3 / L_v2
13.766083308927445

The V3 pool uses the same capital in a more than 13 times efficient way.

Many thanks! That makes it a bit more clear, however I am still insecure. My target is to generally compare the liquidity of a V2 pair with a V3 pool. To answer the simple question "Which pair/pool has more liquidity". Is it enough then to simply compare L_v3 and L_v2 from your example?

Liquidity is a measure of price impact. For V3 pools, to get the in-range liquidity, call the liquidity() function of the pool - that is the L_v3 in the example. It's directly comparable with liquidity computed from the reserves in V2 pools.

I recently wrote this answer how to compare liquidity in V3 pools: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/162508/how-to-compare-liquidity-between-different-dex-pools

Ok I think I got it. Many thanks, also for the link, super useful!

One doubt left - I can directly compare the liquidities, when both pairs' tokens have the same decimals, right? If I want to compare the liquidity of two pools which have token decimals of let's say (18/18) and (18/6), I have to normalize the liquidity of the second pair with the highest token decimal (in this case 18) - right?
